# Set default "From" address to none in Apple Mail

Tags: mail.app

In Apple Mail, is there a way to make the "From" address blank so that you are forced to select and outgoing mail server each time you create a new message. I keep sending from the wrong address!!

Comment: Well, if you want to use the right send from server, there is way to do that, BUT it is not variable, it will be always the same server.

Comment: Ya, that doesn't really solve my problem thought because when I create new messages it auto selects the last mail server I used.

Comment: You are right, it selects the current server you are in (the message is in), but if you want to use another server automagicaly it is possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how make and use "none" in the from field that will remind you to select the correct sending server but:

You can set up the default sending server that is going to be the default from now on.

[image]

> Send new message from

, change to the server of your choice.

Remember all emails from now on will go out from that server, regardless in which server you received them.

Comment: This changed the default server the OP wants to be forced to choose one when sending - so he does not want at all to "Remember all emails from now on will go out from that server," He knows that setting the server name here does that

Comment: You are welcome, I faced same forgetting it problem as well till it was to late when I saw I used the wrong server :(

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to safely prevent sending new emails from a wrong account:

1. At Mail - Settings - Accounts add a new account which you call "INVALID". At "Server Settings" provide invalid credentials for the outgoing email server.
2. Then at Mail - Settings - Composing select "INVALID" in the "Send new message from" dropdown.

Whenenver you compose a new email, this will force you to choose the correct account. Even if you forget to choose the correct account, Mac mail will remind you to do so by prompting that sending is not possible.